# Terminal commands running extremely slow

Tags: performance, terminal, command, homebrew, kubectl

I am currently having an issue where certain terminal commands are running extremely slowly.

Some example commands include: `kubectl` or `brew`

Currently `time kubectl version` takes 14s and `time brew -v` takes around 44s.

I've looked at other threads and they said to check what $PATH is set to, and it seems like mine is set correctly already:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/hardy/.fzf/bin
```

I have also tested with `set -x` to see exactly what is the delay. When I run `kubectl` or `brew` with `set -x` on, I am able to see that it stalls for an extremely long period of time after the command is run. It stalls for about 40s here:

```
brew -v
 + brew -v
```

Both `brew` and `kubectl` are located in `/usr/local/bin`. There are other commands that are located in `/usr/local/bin` that are not running extremely slow. Just a select few are running slow I believe.

Do you guys have any idea what the issue is or how to further debug this?

Comment: what's the current CPU & RAM usage on your mac? Is it always slow or is it only on these commands?

Comment: hi, perhaps a network issue? maybe try `kubectl --v=9` for maximum verbosity or `brew -d -v --display-times` for more tracing.

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the launch delays  back in November (see [here](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/11/macos-big-sur-launch-appears-to-cause-temporary-slowdown-in-even-non-big-sur-macs/) for example). Try turning off all network connectivity, and see if it speeds up (for operations that don't depend on Internet access, that is).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried turning off my network connectivity and the commands sped up significantly. I think it is related to those launch delays. I'll try updating to big sur to see if that helps. I appreciate it!

Comment: @HardyPham If it's the same cause as before, upgrading won't help -- Big Sur does the same check, the problem last time was that the servers were overloaded due to the Big Sur release. Also, it might be some other network-related problem, like a slow/failing DNS resolver. Unless you want to upgrade anyway, I'd do some more troubleshooting first.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Do you happen to know how I could troubleshoot this further?

Comment: I'd first try blocking the OCSP server that was causing trouble in November. Instructions are [here](https://twitter.com/nathanhleung/status/1327000950989496320), though I'd add step 2.5: back up the original hosts file with `sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bkp` . If that has no effect, it's not the same problem, and you can set the hosts file back to normal with `sudo cp /etc/hosts.bkp /etc/hosts` .

Comment: Updating to big sure actually fixed the issue. I appreciate the help @GordonDavisson